# Run process with different user for first time when user profile is not created

Tags: c#, user-profile

I am using below code for running a process with different user. It work fine when user profile is already exist or user login one's in system but it give problem when user is not login to that system because user profile is not exist.
How can i solve this issue?

```
        ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
        myProcess.UserName = username;
        myProcess.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
        myProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.Start(myProcess);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting myProcess.LoadUserProfile = true. I had a similar issue and setting this property was able to resolve my problem.